# Как отобразить данные пользователя в Layout?

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, asp.net-core

Бьюсь с сей проблемой уже некоторое время. Суть такова. В ASP я не профи, поэтому спрашиваю у Вас. Не могу вытащить данные пользователя внутри Layout'а страницы. 
Пробовал по разному. К примеру этот способ не сработал

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using KSM_Agro.Models
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager

@{
    var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);

}
```

Вечно выбивает ошибку на то, что у меня не зарегистрирован IServiceProvider.
Сразу попрошу. Не надо советовать передавать данные пользователя через ViewBag или подобные инструменты. Мне нужно взять именно из Layout. Почитал, что надо добавить в конфигурации через services.AddSingleton или AddTransient. Но и то и то вызывает одну и ту же ошибку No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`[WebApp.Models.User]' has been registered.
Я понимаю что он пишет, но при этом и регистрацию проводил. Что делать не знаю господа.

Comment: Для начала уточните: у вас asp.net или asp.net core? Это _разные_ технологии (из тела вопроса понятно, что именно используется, но поправьте метки). Далее: ef или ef core? Это тоже _разные_ ORM (обе можно использовать в обеих технологиях). Какой именно DI/IoC-фреймворк используется?

Comment: А после того, как вы всё это укажете, можно закрывать тему: ибо нефиг страдать фигнёй. Перенесите код в контроллер и передайте во view готовый результат.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov asp.net core не обязательно подразумевает mvc. Это вполне могут быть razor pages, без контроллера. Топикастаер прямо написал, что не хочет прокидывать данные снаружи - какой смысл это ему советовать :)

Comment: @PashaPash, вы так говорите, как будто лезть базу из вьюхи это нормально

Comment: @АндрейNOP лезть в Identity (в сервис) из вьюхи [в некоторых случаях нормально](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x). Если нужно всего лишь показать имя залогиненного пользователя в мелком приложении - проще дернуть его прямо из шаред вью, чем шаманить, протаскивать его через модель или какой-нибудь ViewBag. Потому что результат одинаковый, а работы больше. А база тут вообще ни при чем.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не хватает регистрации Identity, или при регистрации указан неправильный тип пользователя. Проверьте `Startup.ConfigureServices`, там должна быть строка вида:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()...
```

В ней первый тип-параметр должен совпадать с тем, который вы используете в `@inject UserManager<User>` - это должен быть один и тот же тип `User`.